# ReactJS error on using hooks with react router dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using the react router dom v6(tests) to create routes.
In one of the delete routes I am not getting the result of an api because I have an error.
I'm not able to get through useParams () the parameters passed in the url to do the search in the api.
The error is

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>   See for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
>   ▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
>   useParams
>   C:/wamp64/packages/react-router/modules/index.js:383
>     380 |  * This is useful for components that need to know "active" state, e.g.
>     381 |  * .
>     382 |  */
>   383 | export function useMatch(to) {
>     384 |   let location = useLocation();
>     385 |   let resolvedLocation = useResolvedLocation(to);
>     386 |   // TODO: Try to match search + hash as well
>   View compiled
>   Delete.renderResult
>   C:/wamp64/www/apirest-react/src/actions/Delete/index.js:18
>     15 | 
>     16 |  renderResult = async () => {
>     17 | 
>   18 |      const {id} = useParams();
>        | ^  19 |      const response = await api.get(`/users/delete/${id}/Gla123`);
>     20 |      this.setState({message: response.data.message});

MY CODE:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import api from '../../services/api';
import './styles.css';
export default class Delete extends Component {

    state = {
        message: "Deleting user...",
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.renderResult();
    }

    renderResult = async () => {

        const { id } = useParams();
        const response = await api.get(`/users/delete/${id}/Gla123`);
        this.setState({ message: response.data.message });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="userDeleted">
                <div className="message">{this.state.message}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a **function component**"

Answer (score 2):

you are not able to use hooks inside class components. Instead you should use withRouter HOC and get params from match property.